# How to "simplify" ArcGIS World_Street_Map

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-online-basemaps, streets

I recently started using ArcGIS' export web map function to create static maps. I am using this map server for my operational layer: https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer

However, I don't really like the building footprints.
[image: You can see how the buildings use this sorta 3D style, which I dislike]

Is there any way I can "simplify" them (You can see the building footprints look sort of 3D)?
I would like for the result to look like the google maps building footprints:
[image]

You can see that the building footprints are really simple, using just 2 colors that are easily detectable.

Comment: You could always find another map service, or make your own.

Comment: @Vince Could you provide any resources for such actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ArcGIS Vector Tile Style Editor](https://vtse.arcgis.com/) to create a custom base map.
Open the World Street Map and remove the inner and outer shadow.
[image: before removal].
The shadow wiil be gone.
[image: after]
Then save you custom basemap. The editor will store the customized basemap as a vector tile item with an item ID. You can use the item ID to access the styled basemap.